# Y axis can not be set to logarithmic scale

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-datavisualization

I want a chart with logarithmic scales on both axis' and have the working code below. If I comment in the fifth line starting with `y axis` the code doesn't compile.

```
\begin{tikzpicture} [scale=2]

\datavisualization [
scientific axes,
x axis={logarithmic, ticks={major={at={1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048}}}},
%% y axis={logarithmic, ticks={major={at={0.01, 1, 100, 10000}}}},
visualize as smooth line/.list={nlogn, testedTriangles, edgeFlips}, 
nlogn ={pin in data={text=$2.43184\cdot n\cdot log(n)$}},
testedTriangles={pin in data={text=$\varnothing Anzahl getesteter Dreiecke$}},
edgeFlips={pin in data={text=$\varnothing Anzahl Edge-Flips$}}
]

data [set=nlogn] {
    x, y
    1, 0
    2, 4.86368
    4, 19.45472
    8, 58.36416
    16, 155.63776
    32, 389.0944
    64, 933.82656
    128, 2178.92864
    256, 4980.40832
    512, 11205.91872
    1024, 24902.0416
    2048, 54784.49152
}
data [set=testedTriangles] {
    x, y
    1, 0
    2, 0
    4, 3.5773
    8, 16.5964
    16, 55.4506
    32, 166.9217
    64, 469.8356
    128, 1293.5265
    256, 3583.0332
    512, 9794.2665
    1024, 27411.0824
    2048, 76718.862
}
data [set=edgeFlips] {
    x, y
    1, 0
    2, 0
    4, 0.4331
    8, 4.4301
    16, 17.7114
    32, 52.7935
    64, 131.8179
    128, 305.597
    256, 668.4145
    512, 1411.642
    1024, 2922.9684
    2048, 5960.823
};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

The error message is `Missing number, treated as zero.` and indicating the second last line of the snippet above containing `};`

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a **full** minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)),  starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Your y coordinates contain zeros, that throws errors when using log scaling for obvious reasons.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see the obvious. I used a charting tool to create the data which automatically filtered out invalid rows...